# Weird tmux vim through ssh

Tags: vim, ssh, tmux

First I ssh into this server called `thor`, I set the bash prompt, before I start tmux it looks like following

```
[1.9.3@lizhe] ~ 
→ somecommand
```

after I start tmux, it turns to this

```
[1.9.3@lizhe] ~ 
→    somecommand
```

more space before `somecommand`, after typing an command I hit enter, it looks like this

```
[1.9.3@lizhe] ~ 
→ somecommand
[1.9.3@lizhe] ~ 
→     somecommand
```

another big problem is the vim, it's totally unusable, just check the following screen record, I don't konw how to describe it.

[wierd vim in tmux throug ssh](http://ascii.io/a/2749)

I use `j` `k` to move, but the current line is not it look like, and some lines are not visiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your `TERM` variable is set wrong.

According to the man page for TMUX found [here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1)

> The TERM environment variable must be set to 'screen' for all
>                programs running inside tmux.  New windows will automatically
>                have 'TERM=screen' added to their environment, but care must be
>                taken not to reset this in shell start-up files.

Make sure TERM is set to `screen` or `screen-256color` (You can check this by typing `echo $TERM`). If it is not check your init files such as `.profile` and `.bashrc` and make sure you do not over write the `TERM` variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I set my `term` to `screen-256color` and it works! thank you!